# Making a rotating object rotate with a parent object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a game object which swings back and forth along one of its axis, this is attached to a parent gameObject which moves around a scene. However, when the parent object rotates the child object does not rotate with it.

I expect this is something to do with local vs global space.. however Im at a loss...

This is the code which manages the sweep.

```
    // Increment a timer
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    // Swing the object back and forth based on the rotationLimit and the rotationSpeed
    currentRotation = Mathf.PingPong (timer * rotationSpeed, rotationLimit * 2f) - rotationLimit;

    // Create a temporary variable to store the new rotation
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler (transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y + currentRotation, transform.rotation.z);

    // Set the rotation to the temp var
    transform.rotation = rotation;
```

I considered grabbing the parents rotation and using that instead of the transform.rotation. However, ideally this same script needs to work on a variety of objects, some of which don't have parents. Can anyone advise where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your tags i'm guessing you use Unity. As far as I know, unity supports the concept of a 'SceneGraph'. This allows you to build a tree of game objects, where the children follow the transformation of their parent. 
See this link: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html

ALTERNATIVE - If you want to do this manually:

You should be carefull when manually combining parent/child transformations. The easiest and probably best way to do this is to simply combine the parent and child transformations:

```
ChildWorldTransform = ChildLocalTransform * ParentWorldTransform
```

ChildLocalTransform corresponds to your currentRotation, ParentWorldTransform to the transformation of your parent object. Note that you should multiply the entire transformation as a whole, not just the rotation part!

I also suggest that you do a google for 'scenegraph'